# How to upload image captured from camera and displayed in imageview to firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload image captured from my phone camera, and which is displayed in an imageview on one of the screens, to Firebase storage.I have used FileOutputStream to direct the image to cache data, but the app keeps crashing once I open the camera on my phone

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,   Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(image);

        String destFolder = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(destFolder + "/myBitamp.png");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    }
}


private <storageReference> void uploadImage() {
    if(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() != null);
    storageReference ref = (storageReference)  storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    ((StorageReference) ref).putFile(Uri.parse(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath())).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

error log:
2019-05-17 14:10:41.546 29232-32694/? E/FA: Event can't contain more than 25 params: play_pause, Bundle[{play_time=716612, ad_master_switch=true, mnc_code=40445, language_selection_flow=1, orientation=portrait, action=pause, circle=ka, playback_host=manifest.prod.boltdns.net, searchflow_usertype=3, rsflow_usertype=0, signal_strength_info=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 18 -104 -13 38 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 255 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level  [-128, -115, -110, -105, -97] [-115, -105, -95, -85], operator=AIRTEL, landing_page_atv_plus=0, bitrate=0, source_name=airtel_tv_premium, network_type=4G, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AirtelmainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4997872789649524094, content_id=HOOQ_EPISODE_111281, landing_page_atv=0, content_detail_page_ad_unit=true, content_name=The Maternal Conclusion, content_type=VOD, pre_roll_ad_unit=true, streaming_operator=airtel, cp_name=HOOQ, vsflow_usertype=1, play_session_id=RsglFIqEL1NVFdvh40-1558082341222, app_type=MOBILITY, searchresults_usertype=0, is_drm_content=true, signal_strength_level=4, license_roundtrip_time=856}]

I expect to upload the image captured into my Firebase storage,but as soon as I open the camera, the app crashes.

Comment: What's the error log?

Comment: There is no error in the code, it installs on my phone successfully, but the app crashes every time i try to open camera.

Comment: Please post the error log

Comment: check the log in the logcat on Android Studio.